# Retrieve the user during creation Document PDF Symfony

Tags: symfony, symfony4

How can I retrieve the logged in user (the administrator) when creating the pdf document?

the user is connected.the user is connected, and creates the document from the dashboard

**DocumentController.php**

```
/**
     * @Route("/new", name="document_new", methods={"GET","POST"})
     */
    public function new(Request $request): Response
    {
        
        $document = new Document();
        $document->setCreatedAt(new \DateTime('now'));
        $form = $this->createForm(DocumentType::class, $document);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $document->setUsers($this->getUser());
            $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

            $file = $form['fileDocument']->getData();

            $originalFilename = pathinfo($file->getClientOriginalName(), PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            // this is needed to safely include the file name as part of the URL
            $fileName = transliterator_transliterate('Any-Latin; Latin-ASCII; [^A-Za-z0-9_] remove; Lower()', $originalFilename);
            $fileName = md5(uniqid()) . '.' . $file->guessExtension();

            $file->move(
                $this->getParameter('brochures_directory'),
                $fileName

            );
            $document->setFileDocument($fileName);
            $entityManager->persist($document);
            $entityManager->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('document', array('id' => $document->getId()));
        }

        return $this->render('document/new.html.twig', [
          
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hope this will help you**

```
/**
 * @Route("/new", name="document_new", methods={"GET","POST"})
 * @IsGranted("ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR") // if you want allowed this action only for ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR => replace by role that you want,
 */
public function new(Request $request): Response
{

    // you need juste call helper function $this->getUser() 
    $currentUser =  $this->getUser();

    $document = new Document();
    $document->setCreatedAt(new \DateTime('now'));
    $form = $this->createForm(DocumentType::class, $document);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $document->setUsers($this->getUser());
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $file = $form['fileDocument']->getData();

        $originalFilename = pathinfo($file->getClientOriginalName(), PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        // this is needed to safely include the file name as part of the URL
        $fileName = transliterator_transliterate('Any-Latin; Latin-ASCII; [^A-Za-z0-9_] remove; Lower()', $originalFilename);
        $fileName = md5(uniqid()) . '.' . $file->guessExtension();

        $file->move(
            $this->getParameter('brochures_directory'),
            $fileName

        );
        $document->setFileDocument($fileName);
        $entityManager->persist($document);
        $entityManager->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('document', array('id' => $document->getId()));
    }

    return $this->render('document/new.html.twig', [
      
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ]);
}
```